# Disable dates with range using mydatepicker Angular6

Tags: javascript, datepicker, angular6

im trying to disable previous dates ranging from 35 days ago to years in the past for an example 1990.

```js
public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
  dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  disableDateRanges: {
    begin: 'from 35 days ago';
    end: 'to 1990';
  }
};
```

I've tried this code below but it doesn't work

```js
public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
  dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  disableDateRanges: {
    begin: {
      year: 2018,
      month: 09
      day: 14
    },
    end: {
      year: 1990
      month: 10
      day: 14
    }
  }
};
```

but this gives an error of

> TS2322:
>   Type '{ dateFormat: string; showIncreaseDateBtn: true; showDecreaseDateBtn: true; showClearDateBtn: fal...' is not assignable to type 'IMyDpOptions'.
>   Types of property 'disableDateRanges' are incompatible.
>   Type '{ begin: { year: number; month: number; day: number; }; end: { year: number; month: number; day: ...' is not assignable to type 'IMyDateRange[]'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'begin' does not exist in type 'IMyDateRange[]'.

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your issue, but shouldn't *begin* be before *end*, not after?

Comment: its like that in the docs.